# Window title gets changed when opening the same domain in another tab

Tags: javascript

I am using x.com, initially I have my window title as "one". I am changing the window title through JavaScript as "two". Now if I open the same x.com in another tab, the browser automatically changes the first tab title from "two" to "one". How to avoid this change?

Am using Firefox 13.

Comment: Maybe you could provide some code and tell something about the browser you are using, that would help to answer your question.

Comment: Not seeing this in google chrome at least

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue either. (using Internet Explorer 9.0.8112 and Mozilla Firefox 13.0.1)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't commit the change of the title (which you did clientside with your javascript) to the server, it will deliver the page with the same title you initially declared (`title="one"`).

Changes which you do Clientside are (very generally spoken) not persistent until you save them on the server via a formsubmit or an ajax call.